# An interview "run by"

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the correct word to replace the italic words in the following sentence? John Smith is the interviewer.

"I just heard part of an interview ***run by*** John Smith"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I just heard part of an interview **conducted** by John Smith.*